# Code still compiled eventhough value constructors are given no arguments.

Tags: haskell

```
data World = Green Double | Red Double 
  deriving Show

ws = [Green, Red]
```

As you can see `Green` and `Red` should've been given one argument each. I expect GHC would throw an error at compile-time, but it's not, the code compiled. Is this normal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope MathematicalOrchid don't mind (if you do give a comment and I delete this)

---

It's not really an error - the compiler is doing what you asked it to - the typechecker infers a list of functions `ws :: [Double -> World]` when you enter

```
ws = [Green, Red]
```

that's why it's a good idea to give expected signatures so that the compiler/typechecker will make you aware of your mistakes

```
ws :: [World]
ws = [Green, Red] -- error
```

will give you

```
YourFile.hs:...: Couldn't match expected type `World' …
                with actual type `Double -> World'
    Probable cause: `Green' is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression: Green
    In the expression: [Green, Red]
YourFile.hs:...: Couldn't match expected type `World' …
                with actual type `Double -> World'
    Probable cause: `Red' is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression: Red
    In the expression: [Green, Red]
```